# Lambda expression or Method Reference?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I read in a book (Fischer's *Java Closures and Lambda*, Apress 2015) that method references are preferable to lambda expressions. From my point of view, the lambda expression is more easily understandable to developers who use other languages. Then why does it say the method reference is preferable? Is writing a lambda expression a bad practice in Java 8?

Comment: It's not a "bad practice" it just means that it's not reusable and can't self-reference (recurse).

Comment: Downvoter - please comment!

Comment: Which book is that? Is the author Robert Fischer?

Comment: Yes, the author is Robert Fischer.

Comment: What we've found is: when people first learn lambdas and method refs, they tend to feel that method refs "look weird" and avoid them.  Then they program with them for a while, and all of a sudden their preference "snaps" to the guidance Fisher is offering -- most likely because they've gotten past the "looks weird" reaction, and can see it for what it is.  Fisher's conclusion is in line with our intentions when we added the feature to the language (though there are always exceptions.)  I think you're just stuck in the first stage -- so come back and answer your own question in six months...

Comment: Sure, thanks for encouraging words. I will try to learn more and find the true beauty of the method reference and new features. The second thing amaze me was the vast amount of collectors came along with Java 8.

Answer (score 20):

In the *Lambda Best Practices* section of Chapter 2, Fischer's book says:

> As much as possible, use a method reference instead of a lambda. Method references are not only shorter and easier to read, but using method references will get you thinking directly about the methods as values. This is the code you need to excise from your codebase and your brain:

```
    x -> it.do(x)
```

> If you are naturally writing that code, then you still have not made the leap to thinking at the higher level of functional programming. Once you make that leap, it will become much easier to communicate and work with complex functions, because you will be thinking in types, not in values.

Although I mostly agree with the conclusion, I'm not sure I buy Fischer's line of reasoning. Method references are often, though not always, shorter than the written-out lambda. In the first part he says that method references will help you think about methods as values. OK, but then later he says things will become easier because you'll be thinking in types, not values. I'm not sure what that means.

It's possible to rewrite the example expression he gives as

```
    it::do
```

That's certainly shorter than the original, but it's hard to generalize from a tiny example.

Here's my take on method references vs. written-out lambdas.

If there is a choice between using a lambda expression and a method reference, it is *often* the case that a method reference is preferable. But this is not a hard-and-fast rule, and there are likely to be circumstances where a lambda expression is preferable. It's also somewhat a matter of taste.

If you're familiar with lambda expressions from other languages, then lambda expressions in Java will probably be more immediately familiar than method references. However, I believe this to be a temporary state until you learn method references. Once they're more familiar, the advantages of method references can outweigh the initial unfamiliarity.

Consider this simple example of getting the lengths of strings:

```
List<String> list = ... ;
int[] lengths1 = list.stream().mapToInt(s -> s.length()).toArray();
int[] lengths2 = list.stream().mapToInt(String::length).toArray();
```

In this case, the size of the lambda expression is just about the same as the size of the method reference (in the number of characters). But notice that the method reference contains more type information. It tells the reader that the element type is `String`, which may be helpful in understanding a long pipeline. It is sometimes also helpful to the compiler, if it cannot infer the element type, as sometimes occurs in complex expressions.

Another point is that, using a method reference will often relieve you of the responsibility of coming up with a name for a formal parameter that's simply passed to another method. Naming is often important, but lambda formals are often "garbage" names like `i` `x` or `s` as in this example.

The method reference is a tiny bit more efficient, as it doesn't need to generate a static method that must be called through to get to the String.length() method. But this efficiency is rarely an important consideration.

Consider also this example, deliberately stripped of context:

```
(x, y) -> x + y
```

Is this string concatenation or numeric addition? If numeric, what type? Under the rules of the language, this must be known at compile time, otherwise it's an error. Although it might be clear to the compiler, sometimes this isn't very clear to the reader. Consider instead these method references:

```
String::concat
Integer::sum
Double::sum
```

Using a name for the operation in this case makes it very explicit to the reader about what is intended.